# Smart Quotes and Ligatures in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, ligature, smart-quotes

I have a file `text.txt` which contains very basic latex/markdown. For example, it might be the following.

```
Here is some basic maths: $f(x) = ax + b$ defines a straight line, often called a "linear" function---but it's not _actually_ a linear function, eg $f(0) \ne 0$.
```

I would like to convert this into `html` using `WebTeX`. However, I don't want smart quotes---`"` should be outputted as basic straight lines, not curved on either end---or smart dashes---`---` should be literally three dashes, not an em-dash.

It seems that the `smart` option is good for this: [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), [github 1](https://github.com/dalibo/pandocker/issues/20), [github 2](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2541). However, I can't quite work out the correct syntax. I have tried, for example, the following.

```
pandoc text.txt -f markdown-smart -t markdown-smart -s --webtex -o tex.html
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

I solved this while writing the question, so I'll post the answer below! (Spoiler alert: simply remove `-t markdown-smart`.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53678363/2425163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove `-t markdown-smart`.

```
pandoc text.txt -f markdown-smart -s --webtex -o tex.html
```

I believe that this `-t` is saying "to markdown without smart". We are not trying to output markdown, but rather html. If the version with `-t` is viewed, then one sees that the code for embedding various images is included. If this is pasted into a markdown editor, then it should show up.

To get html, simply remove this.